# How to solve a simple linear equation in ring $(\mathbb Z_4,+4,\cdot 4) $

Tags: linear-algebra

How do I solve the following simple linear equations in ring $(\mathbb Z_4,+4,\cdot 4)$:

$$ 2\cdot x+1=0$$ $$3\cdot x+1=0$$

Where $+4$ and $\cdot 4$ are operations addition and multiplication modulo $4$

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: There are only $4$ elements in $\Bbb{Z}/4\Bbb{Z}$. Try them and see which work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that $2x+1\equiv0$ is equivalent to $2x\equiv -1\equiv 3$. Now you have to find $x\in \mathbb{Z}_4$ such that $2x=3$. By testing with every element in $\mathbb{Z}_4$  you will get that there is no such $x\in \mathbb{Z}_4$. So there is no solution for this equation.

In general, if $p$ is a prime number $\mathbb{Z}_p$ is a field, so you can prove that there are always solutions in  $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for equations of type $ax+b\equiv 0$ with $a,b\in \mathbb{Z}_p$.

However $4$ is not a prime number so this is the kind of things that happen when you try to solve equations in something which is not a field.

For the other equation, observe that $3x+1\equiv 0$ is equivalent to $3x\equiv -1\equiv 3$. So clearly $x=1$ is a solution for your equation and you can check is the only one.

Answer (score 1):

$3x+1\equiv0\pmod4\iff 3x\equiv3\pmod4\iff x\equiv1\pmod4$.

---

$2x+1\equiv1\pmod2,$ so $2x+1\not\equiv0\pmod4$.

Answer (score -1):

For example, the solution for $2x+1=0$ is $x=2^{-1}(-1)$. Observe that, $-1=3$, and you need to find $v =2^{-1}$, that is, the integer such that $2v=1$.

Comment: $2$ is not a unit modulo $4$.

Comment: @jelena633 No, you are entirely right.